# Update Preference List

Tags: android, android-listview, preferences

i'm trying to update my list in a preference with onPreferenceClick method. But the list isn't updated. onPreferenceClick is executed, because i got the names and showed it in the log, but not updated.

```
public class TransferPreference extends PreferenceFragment {
    private TransferHelper transferHelper = new TransferHelper();
    private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    private CharSequence[] charSequence;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_transfer);

        final MultiSelectListPreference preferenceTeams = (MultiSelectListPreference) findPreference("preferenceTranser_multiSelectListPreference_teams");
        preferenceTeams.setPersistent(false);
        preferenceTeams.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                names = transferHelper.getServerTeams(getActivity());
                int size = names.size();
                charSequence = names.toArray(new CharSequence[size]);
                preferenceTeams.setEntries(charSequence);
                preferenceTeams.setEntryValues(charSequence);
                return false;   
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I also tried this in onPreferenceClick:

```
Editor editor = preference.getEditor();
editor.clear();
names = transferHelper.getServerTeams(getActivity());
for (String name : names) {
    editor.putString(name, name);
}
editor.commit();
```

If i put the following code direct in the oncreate method (and not in the listener method), the names are displayed. But only on its creation, like the name says :)

```
names = transferHelper.getServerTeams(getActivity());
int size = names.size();
charSequence = names.toArray(new CharSequence[size]);
preferenceTeams.setEntries(charSequence);
preferenceTeams.setEntryValues(charSequence);
```

Has anyone an idea?
Sorry for my bad english and thanks for help.

edit: i alos tried to add my code additional in this method, but no update.

```
@Override
public void onResume()
```